# Flash in Chrom(ium) 73

Tags: flash, 19.04

I am aware flash is EOL. However, I need it for http://sciencenetlinks.com/media/filer/2017/12/21/evolution.html. according to https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/is-flash-installed however trying to use flash results in "Right Click to enable Adobe Flash". when I do that it does nothing.

Edit: I have chromium Version 73.0.3683.103 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 19.04 (64-bit) and https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/is-flash-installed says Yes
Flash 32.0.0 is installed in this browser

Edit 2: about:components does **not** have flash recognized.

in chrome it looks like 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAjI8.jpg
something about the sandbox broke it. --no-sandbox "fixed it"

Comment: Are you sure it's not "Click to enable Adobe Flash"?  I have checked that link in both Chromium Version 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 18.04 (64-bit) and Chrome Version 73.0.3683.103 (Official Build) (64-bit) and once I enable it by clicking and allowing it it works fine.

Comment: Do you have Chromium as a snap or a .deb package? You can find out by running the command `which chromium-browser`

Comment: Its a deb package. I used `sudo apt install chromium-browser` and `sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin`

Comment: This is a [Chromium bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1825497), and it's about to be fixed very soon. (Already fixed in eoan.)

Answer (score 0):

I did use https://packages.ubuntu.com/ and looking in your version bio,  disco etc in the Web group for pepperflash player,
install it, restart your Chromium and for me flashplayer worked.